# Godot Viewport Node won't move with Parent Node

Tags: camera, viewport, godot

I am trying to have a Sprite 3D have a Viewport texture and I set up my Nodes like this:
[image]
When I added Portal1 to another scene and moved it, the everything moved except the Viewport Node and Everything under it:
Before:[image]
After:[image]

As you can see the Camera didn't move and I figured out it's because the Viewport didn't move. I have tried multiple combinations and nothing works. How can I get the Viewport node to move with the Parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to structure the scene tree that will do what you want. The reason being that the `Viewport` is the root of the transformations. The `Viewport` itself does not have a transformation (so it does not makes sense to speak of the moving the `Viewport`), and Godot does not resolve transformations pass a `Viewport`.

What you can do is have the your scene root copy its `global_transform`. Something like this (if it is intended to be moving all the time):

```
extends Spatial


onready var root := $Viewport/Root as Spatial


func _process(_delta: float) -> void:
    root.global_transform = global_transform
```

Or like this (which is better if it rarely moves):

```
extends Spatial


onready var root := $Viewport/Root as Spatial


func _ready() -> void:
    set_notify_transform(true)


func _notification(what: int) -> void:
    if what == NOTIFICATION_TRANSFORM_CHANGED:
        root.global_transform = global_transform
```

*And you can make it a `tool` script if you want it to work on the editor. Be aware that you will need to reload the scene in the editor for it to begin working.*

With a scene tree something like this:

```
Portal
├ Viewport
│ └ Root
│   └ Camera
└ Sprite3D
```

With the script attached to `Portal`.

Note that I'm not copying the `global_transform` to the `Camera` but to a new `Node` which I called `Root` so you can still move the `Camera` relative to it.

Comment: Thanks you this helps! I don't know how I didn't think of that. Haha. Thanks again.